# Chromecast API not calling sessionListener() call back

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm building a Chromecast Sender application and I can successfully cast a session.  However I can only cast once.  When I disconnect my sessionListener callback never fires, which is problematic because that is where I set my `sessionUpdate` listener.  Without that it is not possible to tell when a session ends in order to reset the session and do any clean up, which means I can't recast anything because I have no way of knowing if a session is valid or not.

As far as I can tell the problem is in `cast_sender.js` which is conveniently obfuscated so I could be wrong.

I'm setting up my ApiConfig as follows:

```
 apiConfig = new _chrome.cast.ApiConfig(
   sessionRequest,
   _sessionListener.bind(this),
   _receiverListener.bind(this));
```

`_receiverListener` is fired as expected and I have debugged `cast_sender.js` to the point where I can see my function `_sessionListener` being passed in and set properly on line #837 of `cast_sender.js`, here:

```
835 chrome.cast.dd = function(a, c, d, e, f) {
836   this.sessionRequest = a;
837   this.sessionListener = c;
838   this.receiverListener = d;
839   this.autoJoinPolicy = e || chrome.cast.Fb.TAB_AND_ORIGIN_SCOPED;
840   this.defaultActionPolicy = f || chrome.cast.Jb.CREATE_SESSION;
841   this.customDialLaunchCallback = null;
842 };
```

that function appears to be called on line #2441, here:

```
2440 b.Wf = function(a) {
2441  this.B && this.B.sessionListener(a.message);
2442 };
```

I have set a breakpoint there and it is never called. At this point I have reached an impasse, any thoughts?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in CastVideos-chrome-material (https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome-material) which uses the SessionListener too?

Comment: I actually think I've solved the problem.   I set up my sender based on the CastHelloText-chrome example in github which appears to set the session incorrectly.  I will be submitting a pull request for my fix later today.

Comment: @AliNaddaf https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-chrome/pull/14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem in the callback passed to the `cast.requestSession()` function of the example code I copy/pasted here https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-chrome/blob/master/chromehellotext.html#L162

I've submitted a pull request for a fix which resolves the issue here https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-chrome/pull/14 but I doubt it will be pulled in considering that it looks like they have PRs sitting in queue unaddressed for several years.